# Notebook Hybrid Graphic on external monitor

Tags: graphics-card

I got an Dell Vostro notebook with AMD Hybrid Graphic.

I want to play games on an external monitor, but the problem is, that if you connect an external monitor the notebook uses always the integrated intel graphic instead of the AMD chip.

Is there a way to overcome this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using LucidLogix Virtu MVP which allows you to combine discrete and internal graphics to increase performance. It also enables you to route to your desired output. Virtu supports platforms based on Sandy Bridge, Ivy Bridge and Haswell Intel Core Processors and works seamlessly with most Nvidia and AMD/ATI graphics cards. Hope this works for you.

[Virtu MVP](http://lucidlogix.com/products/virtu-mvp-2-0-for-windows/)